# How to find out if a folder exists and how to create a folder?

Tags: c++, directory

I'm trying to create a folder if it doesn't exist. I'm using Windows and I am not interested on my code working in other platforms.

Never mind, I found the solution. I was just having a inclusion problem. The answer is:

```
#include <io.h>   // For access().
#include <sys/types.h>  // For stat().
#include <sys/stat.h>   // For stat().
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string strPath;
   cout << "Enter directory to check: ";
   cin >> strPath;

   if ( access( strPath.c_str(), 0 ) == 0 )
   {
      struct stat status;
      stat( strPath.c_str(), &status );

      if ( status.st_mode & S_IFDIR )
      {
         cout << "The directory exists." << endl;
      }
      else
      {
         cout << "The path you entered is a file." << endl;
      }
   }
   else
   {
      cout << "Path doesn't exist." << endl;
   }
```

Comment: Seriously?  Your initial question had no code fragment, and this code does not reflect the question.  It was more of a "What's wrong with my code [that I didn't post]?"

Comment: You should post the edit as an answer and accept it.

Comment: It didn't let me post it as an answer or a comment.

Comment: `#include <sys/io.h>`, not `#include <io.h>`, right?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The POSIX-compatible call is `mkdir`.  [It](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mkdir.html) silently fails when the directory already exists.

If you are using the Windows API, then [`CreateDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363856%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is more appropriate.

Answer (score 13):

Use `boost::filesystem::exists` to check if file exists.

Answer (score 12):

`boost::filesystem::create_directories` does just that: Give it a path, and it will create all missing directories in that path.

Comment: Searching on Google for `boost check directory exists then create C++` brought me here as the first search result. Thanks. +1.