# FireBreath Write to AppData LocalLow From Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, npapi, firebreath, userappdatapath

I have a FireBreath plugin source that somebody wrote that I'm trying to make compatible with Internet Explorer. In this plugin, `.flv` video is downloaded and then FFMPEG is executed within the Windows CMD.EXE to convert the `.flv` to another media format. The command is run from `CreateProcess(...)`.

My problem is that the `CreateProcess` command always returns an error code 5, which I suppose is Access Denied. The command works on the command line (FFMPEG does the conversion correctly), but not from the plugin.

Note, that I have gotten the AppData path with:

```
string appDataPath = FB::System::getLocalAppDataPath("My Company Name LLC")
```

Is there a registry key somewhere that must be added to "initialize" this path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming it doesn't work on Chrome/Firefox as well.

1. If you are trying to run your own executable - specify the absolute path.
2. Try to load a DLL in the same folder using `LoadLibrary` - I think this could provide better info of whether or not the path is correct.

If IE is the only browser you are having problems with, read [Understanding and Working in Protected Mode Internet Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250462%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

See also [FireBreath Tips and Tricks](http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/Tips+and+Tricks).

Comment: Indeed, I solved my problem by reading http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250462%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#dse_stlip where it says lower the process integrity by using CreateProcessAsUser(...).

Answer (score 1):

getLocalAppDataPath just returns a path to the localLow area in your user profile; in this case, it would most likely give you:

```
C:\Users\YourUser\AppData\LocalLow\My Company Name LLC
```

It doesn't ensure that directory has been created or anything like that.  If you want to do that I'd recommend [using boost::filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981947/), since that would then be cross platform, but you can really use anything.

[How to find out if a folder exists and how to create a folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621944) has some other good ideas mostly using system API calls (windows only).